# Partial string match between dataframes, with no overwriting of existing data

Tags: python, pandas

In my opinion, this is a difficult one. Basically, I'm trying to classify a column in one dataframe based on a partial string match and classification from another dataframe. There's an added complication that I don't want to overwrite existing classifications.

I want to create the classifications in the following fruit dataframe:

```
description                  classification
a phrase about bananas       NaN
a polemic on green apples    NaN
sentence about kumquats      NaN
paragraph about lemons       NaN
a treatise on kiwi fruit     NaN
a sentence on bananas        NaN
a soliloquy on apples        NaN
```

I'm doing this with a classification dataframe, which is of the form:

```
keyword          classification
bananas          vitamin K
green apples     too sharp
kiwi fruit       hairy
kumquats         basically inedible
lemons           G&T
apples           nice
```

I want to take the keyword from the classification dataframe, and search for it in the description of the description of the fruit dataframe. If found, I want to add the appropriate classification from the classification dataframe to the fruit dataframe.

It gets more complicated. There are times when one keyword is included in another (for example, "apples" is also in "green apples"). To deal with this, I'll match on phrases first, and then on lone keywords (I'll iterate through a list of keywords that has been sorted so that phrases come first). This means that when I write the classification into the fruit dataframe, I'll need to check whether there's a classification already in place and, if there is one, I'll just keep it in place and not overwrite it.

Ultimately, I'd end up with this:

```
description                  classification
a phrase about bananas       vitamin K
a polemic on green apples    too sharp
sentence about kumquats      basically inedible
paragraph about lemons       G&T
a treatise on kiwi fruit     hairy
a sentence on bananas        vitamin K
a soliloquy on apples        nice
```

I can do this easily, if messily, enough in a procedural way. How do I do it in true Pandas fashion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve it. Thanks to @AndreyF and @MaxU for inspiration.

First, create a list of the keywords, then sorted the list to put the longest phrases first (this helps deal with the 'green apples' and 'apples' problem, as long as the classification isn't overwritten).

```
keyword_list = classification_df['keyword'].tolist()
keyword_list.sort(key=lambda x: len(x.split()), reverse=True)
```

Create a dict of keywords and descriptions from the classification_df:

```
keyword_dict = dict(zip(classification_df['keyword'], classification_df['classification']))
```

Go through each of the keywords, get the corresponding description from the keyword dict. Then write the description into the appropriate parts in the fruit dataframe:

```
for current_keyword in keyword_list:
    current_description = keyword_dict[current_keyword]
    fruit_dataframe.loc[fruit_dataframe['description'].str.contains(current_keyword) & fruit_dataframe['classification'].isnull(), 'classification'] = current_description
```

The important part is this line:

```
fruit_dataframe.loc[fruit_dataframe['description'].str.contains(current_keyword) & fruit_dataframe['classification'].isnull(), 'classification'] = current_description
```

It uses two boolean masks. The first finds descriptions that match the description in the fruit dataframe, the second finds classifications that are NaN. By using a logical & on these two masks, I end up identifying the rows where the classification is needed.

It appears to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [95]: pat = '.*\b?({})\b?.*'.format(cl.keyword.str.cat(sep='|'))

In [96]: pat
Out[96]: '.*(bananas|green apples|kiwi fruit|kumquats|lemons|apples).*'

In [97]: df['classification'] = \
             df.description.str.replace(pat, r'\1') \
               .map(cl.set_index('keyword')['classification'])
```

**Result:**

```
In [98]: df
Out[98]:
                 description      classification
0     a phrase about bananas           vitamin K
1  a polemic on green apples                nice
2    sentence about kumquats  basically inedible
3     paragraph about lemons                 G&T
4   a treatise on kiwi fruit               hairy
5      a sentence on bananas           vitamin K
6      a soliloquy on apples                nice
```

**Classification DF:**

```
In [99]: cl
Out[99]:
        keyword      classification
0       bananas           vitamin K
1  green apples           too sharp
2    kiwi fruit               hairy
3      kumquats  basically inedible
4        lemons                 G&T
5        apples                nice
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out. Does it matter if the list of keywords gets big - say a few thousand?

Comment: @user4896331, i think you should give it a try. I myself never tried it with that big RegEx strings...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the true Pandas fashion but I would convert the classification DF into a dictionary of the form (keyword: classification) to allow fast lookup for keywords.

```
keyword_dict = dict(zip(class_df['keyword'], class_df['values']))
```

Then I would use the `apply` method to fill the classification column:

```
def search_keyword(row):
    phrase_words = row['description'].split(' ') # or find a smarter way to split words
    for word in phrase_words:
         if word in keyword_dict:
             return keyword_dict[word]

fruit_dataframe['classification'] = fruit_dataframe.apply(search_keyword, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a shot. Would this approach match phrases as well as single keywords?

Comment: It can if you'll split the description column correctly. It is also possible to try and find the keyword within the description but it will be slower.